# A simple javascript number onchange function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, onchange

I have a simple bit of javascript code that I think should be working, but it isn't. The idea for now is basically just to change the content of a div when a number has been input to a box. I'll make it do something more complicated later, but I need it to work first.

So I have this HTML page:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="here" onkeyup="revChange()" />
</form>
<div name="there"></div>
```

running with the following javascript:

```
var revChange = function () {
    document.there.innerHTML = "<p>Thing</p>";
};
```

The result is that nothing happens when I enter anything in the input box, it just stays blank. I've tried using onchange, onkeypress, onblur, onkeyup, I've tried the function with brackets, without brackets, using arguments in the brackets (including this.value), I've tried putting several different things inside the function, I've even tried just calling the function directly from the script. No matter what I do, this function does not seem to want to do anything. I can not work out what is going on, so I would like some explanation if possible. Oh yea, and this is just pure javascript, not jQuery or anything.

Comment: `document.querySelector('div[name="there"]').innerHTML="<p>Thing</p>";`

Answer (score 0):

`document.there.innerHTML` is not how you should reference a non form element.  Give it an id, and use getElementById

Comment: That was how it was originally, but the problem here is more that the function is not loading in at all.

Comment: I was trying this code just earlier in jsfiddle too. The difference between our attempts seemed to be that mine was set to 'onLoad'.

Comment: @Honback: Yep, a common mistake. You can read more about the settings in the jsFiddle documentation: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-settings-sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your function to:

```
var revChange = function (ref) {
 document.getElementsByName("there")[0].innerHTML = ref.value;
};
```

Also change your html to:

```
 <form>
    <input type="text" name="here" onkeyup="revChange(this)" />
    <div name="there"></div>
 </form>
```

This should work.

Comment: This will presumably select the `input` element.

Comment: @FelixKling , if you look closely, "there" is the name of div. So it will select the div.

Comment: But you are  accessing the first of the selected elements, and elements are usually selected in the order they appear in the document. And the input comes before the div.

Comment: @FelixKling, I am using getElementsByName() which will select only the element having name="there". And the input has the name "here" but the div has the name "there".

Answer (score 0):

You should change the name attribute on your div to an id, and use getElementById

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var revChange = function () {
    document.getElementById("there").innerHTML = "<p>Thing</p>";
};
</script>

<form>
    <input type="text" name="here" onkeyup="revChange()" />
</form>
<div id="there"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be working at my end

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="here" onkeyup="revChange(this)" />
</form>
<div name="there" id="das"></div>
<script>
var revChange = function (abd) {
    document.getElementById('das').innerHTML = abd.value;
};
</script>
```